# Convert a means of transport into an animal

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay

*Step 1:*

> *Consider a means of transport.*

*Step 2:*

> *Insert two consecutive letters in the alphabet to the middle of the word in step 1.*

*You have now obtained the name of an animal.*

***Which animal did you obtain and what was the means of transport in step 1?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> Bobcat

And the mode of transportation is

> Boat (add in "bc" in the middle to get the animal)

Comment: This must be it. Beat me by a few seconds. 

Comment: Just curious, what was the thought process to arrive at this answer for you?

Comment: @justhalf I'm sorry to say I looked at a list of animals and searched for transportation.  I'm just lucky it was in the B's, not the Z's!

Comment: So you try to find, for each animal, possible transportation in the animal name? Cool.

Comment: @justhalf Besides, the number of letters in the means of transportation must be even.